# Calculating change area using NDVI in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, vegetation-index

I am new to Google Earth Engine and JavaScript. I am trying to visualize and calculate the changed area from the NDVI of 2 years (Landsat 8 surface reflectance).

Can anyone help me to extract the area as a separate layer and calculate this area?

So far, I have done the following code:

```
Map.centerObject(Sundarban ,8);
Map.addLayer(Sundarban,{},'Sundaban');


/////Pre Ndvi Calculation////////

var Preimg1 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_137045_20190123')
.clip(Sundarban);
var Preimg2 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_138045_20190130')
.clip(Sundarban);

///Mosaic////
var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Preimg2, Preimg1]).mosaic()
print(mosaic)

///Rescaling////
var Preimage = ee.Image(mosaic);
var rescale = Preimage.divide(10000);


var rgbVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 2000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var rgbVis2 = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.2,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

/////Show////
Map.addLayer(Preimage, rgbVis, 'Original');
Map.addLayer(rescale, rgbVis2, 'Rescaled');

/////NDVI Calculation/////
var ndviWithoutrescaled = Preimage.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4'])
var ndvirescaled = rescale.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4'])

/////Show NDVI/////
Map.addLayer(ndviWithoutrescaled,{min:-1, max:1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'ndvi original pre');
Map.addLayer(ndvirescaled,{min:-1, max:1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'ndvi rescale pre')


//////////////////
//////Post////////
//////////////////

var Postimg1 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_137045_20200126').clip(Sundarban);
var Postimg2 = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR/LC08_138045_20200101').clip(Sundarban);


/////Mosaic////
var mosaicP = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages([Postimg2, Postimg1]).mosaic()
print(mosaicP)

/////Rescaling////
var Postimage = ee.Image(mosaicP);
var rescale = Postimage.divide(10000);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 2000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var rgbVis2 = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.2,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

/////Show////
Map.addLayer(Postimage, rgbVis, 'Original');
Map.addLayer(rescale, rgbVis2, 'Rescaled');

/////calculate NDVI////
var ndviWrescaled = Postimage.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4'])
var ndvirescaled = rescale.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4'])

/////Show NDVI/////
Map.addLayer(ndviWrescaled,{min:-1, max:1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'ndvi original post');
Map.addLayer(ndvirescaled,{min:-1, max:1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']}, 'ndvi rescale post')
```